# Oracle comparing timestamp with date

Tags: oracle

I have a timestamp field and I just want to compare the date part of it in my query in Oracle

How do I do that,

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
WHERE date(field1) = '2012-01-01'
```

Comment: You should **not** rely on implicit data conversion. `'2012-01-01'` is not a date, it's character literal. You should always use `to_date()` or an ANSI DATE literal to make sure your SQL doesn't break when NLS settings are different.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You can [truncate](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions201.htm) the date part:

```
select * from table1 where trunc(field1) = to_date('2012-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

The trouble with this approach is that any index on `field1` wouldn't be used due to the function call.

Alternatively (and more index friendly)

```
select * from table1 
 where field1 >= to_timestamp('2012-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') 
   and field1 < to_timestamp('2012-01-02', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Answer (score 4):

You can truncate the date

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
WHERE trunc(field1) = to_Date('2012-01-01','YYY-MM-DD')
```

Look at the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/25ee2/4) for more examples.

Answer (score 2):

`to_date` format worked for me. Please consider the date formats:
`MON-`, `MM`, `.`, `-`.

```
t.start_date >= to_date('14.11.2016 04:01:39', 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
t.start_date <=to_date('14.11.2016 04:10:07', 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```