# SQL - Oracle compare data in two columns of one table

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, timestamp, compare

Can we compare the columns of same table and get a result by selecting all the rows where both columns data does not match. Compare CREATE_DATE and UPDATE_DATE

Table with data

[image]

Expected output:

[image]

Comment: Is it possible also that one of the columns shows `null` and the other a non-null value? Do you need to catch those cases too?

Comment: @Kris, please update this thread by accepting an answer or commenting on each solution why it doesnt work for your posted problem :) This helps with SEO and the next person with same problem as you had

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE TIME_CREATED <> UPDATE_DATE
```

There should be no issue comparing date to timestamp, please update your OP if you have tried this already

If there is an issue, read this post and try something like this:

[Oracle comparing timestamp with date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12609487/oracle-comparing-timestamp-with-date) (also shows use of truncate to disregard time of day)

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE to_timestamp(TIME_CREATED,'D/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS') <> UPDATE_DATE
```

OR

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE TIME_CREATED <> TO_DATE(UPDATE_DATE,'DD.MM.YYYY:HH24:MI:SS')
```

You might have to play with the timestamp format a bit, see https://www.akadia.com/services/ora_date_time.html

Comment: Did not work for me in Oracle, you may try an example.

Comment: @Kris, not work how? It also might help if you put your data/table and the code you tried into https://www.tutorialspoint.com/oracle_terminal_online.php or similar tool, so i can see what your presented with and help with whats most likely just timestamp format